# Convert Arraylist to message

Tags: android

How do i convert an arraylist into a message

This is for converting an msg to arraylist.

```
ArrayList extractData = (ArrayList) msg.obj;
```

How do i do the opposite?
Is this right?

```
Message msg=(Message) arraylist;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use like this if you have any Message object(just the reverse) :

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.obj = arrayList
```

Or you can go for **setData(Bundle b)** method, but as you have only on object, this is ok.

Comment: We need to iterate thru the array list.

    ArrayList <Message> arraylist=new Arraylist<Message>();
    for(Message msg:arraylist){
    //do anything with the message
    }

Comment: what is the problem then if you are creating array list of Message then it will work fine.